# Relate an input to a button in php

Tags: php, sql

I have a script that creates a series of inputs and buttons, retreiving them from a database like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<input value='".$row['val']."'/><button type='submit'>delete</button>";
}
```

This script can retreive any number of rows from the database. And the delete button is supposed to delete the input right next to it like this:

```
$sql="DELETE FROM $tbl WHERE ......";
$delete= mysql_query($sql5, $dbh) or die ("there was a problem");
```

My question is... is there a way to relate each button with the input next to it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer is "yes".  But, as with most things, depends on info you haven't included.  As most tables should have a unique identifier column (typically called `id`), then you would simply change your input or button markup to include the ID: `echo "<input name='row[" . $row['id'] . "]' value='" . $row['val'] . "'/ ><button type='submit' name='delete[" . $row['id'] . "]'>delete</button>`

Comment: if you'd like to use `jQuery` and `ajax` this would be quite easy (i tell you if you want to). otherwise you have to submit form-data to the same (or another) `php` page.

Comment: yes, I don't mind using ajax if it's possible could you please explain me?

Comment: @cale_b ok I have an ID on my table, but whenever I make the post of this button how does the POST variable know to which one of the array am I referring to?

Comment: In your php file that handles the form `post`, to handle a delete: `$deleted = $_POST['delete']; foreach ($deleted AS $id => $x) {.. query to delete row with $id ..}`.  (Note: this needs validation, etc, but will get you started)

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing your code as a starting point, make some changes like so:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<input value='".$row['val']."'/><button name='delete[" . $row['id'] . "]' type='submit'>delete</button>";
}
```

Then, where the form gets posted to, in your php:

```
// Check if the delete button was posted and get the value
$delete = (isset($_POST['delete'])) ? $_POST['delete'] : NULL;
// $delete should contain an array of ids.  Iterate over them
foreach((array)$delete AS $id=>$x) {
    // NOTE: DO NOT use mysql_ - used here ONLY because your question contains mysql_
    $sql="DELETE FROM [table] WHERE id = " . (int)$id;
    // Delete the record where the id matches
    // Also - on your die, let's SEE the problem, by echoing mysql_error()
    $results = mysql_query($sql, $dbh) or die ("there was a problem<br>" . mysql_error());
    if ($results) {
        // .. code to run if query executed successfully...
    }
}
```

**Do not use mysql_**
I can't leave an answer without telling you it is *insecure* and a bad idea to use the [mysql_ database extension](https://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).  It's deprecated in php 5.5.

See [Choosing a database API](https://php.net//manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for help with choosing / switching to mysqli or PDO

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use button and input together this way.

You can achieve it this way:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  echo '<input type="submit" name="'.$row['val'].'" value="delete" />";
}
```

Or you can create many forms - one for each record and set input type as hidden.

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question.  In fact, this should just be a comment, as it purely corrects something about how they are coding, and does not attempt to answer the question.